# yum install <package> not working

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, yum, ambari

I tried installing Ambari using the yum install process. But Ambari requires a few dependencies such as opens and postgresql-server.

When I try to install these packages using `yum install openssl`, I get the error:

> No package openssl available. Nothing to do

I tried checking the repository list by:

```
yum repository all
```

No repos show up.

I am new at this and need help to setup my yum default repositories from scratch. Any help would be appreciated.

My system is Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting openssl error, try installing openssl first on your system and add its path to your env variable.
Then try running yum install

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you need use apt

```
apt install openssl
```